# How do I calculate cumulative sum for last 7 rows on a specific date in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I have a table that has these columns: user_id, day, valueA, valueB.
I'd like to calculate the running sum of last 7 rows of valueA and valueB for each user that has data on a specific day, for example '2020-08-01'.

(Note: Users only have a row when their valueA and valueB is not zero so there are some dates not in the table.)

I tried this query:

```
select user_id, day,
          sum(valueA) over(partition by user_id rows between 7 preceding and current row) as last_7_A,
          sum(valueB) over(partition by user_id rows between 7 preceding and current row) as last_7_B
from table where day='2020-08-01'
```

But this query doesn't calculate the running sum and returns me the valueA and valueB on date 2020-08-01

I could just calculate on each day and select the date I want but that'll be really inefficient. Any ideas how to add the date constraint and let it just calculate on just one row's last 7 running sum for each user?

Comment: It is unclear what you want.  Can you please provide some sample data and an example of what you expect to see?  It is not clear whether a `user_id` can have more than one row per `day`.  Also, are you certain that you want the summary to show the running total for the "last 7 rows" instead of the "last 7 `day` values"?

Answer (score 0):

As per question:
sum of last 7 rows for each user for a particular date, this might work

```
select user_id, sum(valueA) "sum of valueA", sum(valueB) "sum of valueB"
from sample_table
where id in (
    select id
    from sample_table
    where day='2020-08-08'
    order by id desc limit 7)
group by user_id;
```